# Parsing tab delimited txt file PHP fgetcsv hangs / not ending / exiting function

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, fgetcsv

This function is pretty generic its intended to parse a txt file that is delimited with a tab, the files im trying to parse is geonames database, it tops out at 1953146 results every time and from which point nothing happens at all, no more querys and doesnt exit, counting the lines i can see there is 8,000,000 lines in the file so im guessing it is stalled, errors are enabled and there is no error returned php_memory is set to 2048M execution time is set to unlimited.

```
<?php

function table_populate($table,$file,$columns){
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $lines = count(explode("\n",file_get_contents($file)));
    $i = 0;
    while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, "\t")) !== false && $i < $lines) {
        if(preg_match('[#]',$line['0'])){
          // do nothing row is commented out
        }else{
          $row = '';
          $comma = '';
          for ($z = 0; $z < count($line); $z++) {
            $row .=  $comma."'".$line[$z]."'";
            $comma = ', ';
          }
          $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (".$columns.") VALUES (".$row.")";

        }
        $i++;
    }   
    fclose($handle);
    return;
}

?>
```

Comment: I'd suggest you check the formatting of your file; 1953146 is not a special number in some abstract sense, so my guess is there's an error in the file format at that point. Be especially on the lookout for an extra or missing `\n`, extra `#`, or a shift in how line endings are marked (look for `\r` characters).

Comment: Also, make sure the encoding stays consistent and you don't have a BOM (byte order mark) suddenly make an appearance. I have run across .txt and .csv files that suddenly change encoding for no apparent reason, which breaks parser routines like this one.

Comment: One other thought - you say "no more querys," but your code above doesn't actually attempt to execute any queries, so I wonder if you're missing something there. For what it's worth, the way you are doing this -- 8,000,000 one-row queries rather than a few huge queries or even just `LOAD DATA INFILE` -- is going to be *painfully* slow. Be sure it's not a connection timeout (look at the PHP and web server logs).

Comment: sorry the code above doesnt include the mysql query function call however in the original it is there, what i dont quite understand is that `count(explode("\n",file_get_contents($file)))` outputs around 8,000,000 but then fgetcsv fails after the magic number of rows just stalls after 8 hours nothing happens doesnt exit with error and it doesnt continue .

Comment: My guess is that it is overwhelming the server and/or you are losing your connection somewhere in there. I would try LOAD DATA INFILE instead of lots of SELECT statements. This shouldn't take 8 hours; LOAD DATA INFILE can probably handle it in a few minutes.

Comment: Ed is correct `LOAD DATA INFILE` was the only way i could get this to work